# Dates array sort in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Is there possible way to sort an array with values like this type of dates?

```
$dates = [
    "June 8-12",
    "June 15-19",
    "June 22-26",
    "June 29 - July 2",
    "July 10-24",
    "July 6-10",
    "July 27-31",
    "July 13-17",
    "July 20-24",
    "July 8",
    "August 3-7",
    "August 10-14"
];
```

Comment: 1 - What effort have you made; and 2 - These are not dates in a programmatic sense, they are strings. They are all over the place.

Comment: Right. they are dates of string types unfortunately which can not be converted to UNIX timestamp via strToTime()

Comment: At the most beginning. when I received them from DB, they were more shuffled. So this is the result that I can bring to at this moment

Comment: You need to standardise them. In their current state, it's a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

First, I truncate the interval to keep only the begin date (I think it is the most logical thing to do, but you can adapt to your needs).

Then, I build dates object (and take a leap year to avoid problems with 29th February).

Finally, you can rely on the date object comparisons to sort your dates :

```
$dates = [
    "June 8-12",
    "June 15-19",
    "June 22-26",
    "June 29 - July 2",
    "July 10-24",
    "July 6-10",
    "July 27-31",
    "July 13-17",
    "July 20-24",
    "July 8",
    "August 3-7",
    "August 10-14",
];

function myCompDates($s1, $s2)
{
    // if interval, keep only the begin date
    if(strpos($s1, '-') !== false) $s1 = trim(explode('-', $s1)[0]) ;
    if(strpos($s2, '-') !== false) $s2 = trim(explode('-', $s2)[0]) ;
    
    // create Date object for both string
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F d', '2004 ' . $s1);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F d', '2004 ' . $s2);
    
    // use date object comparison
    if( $d1 == $d2 ) return 0 ;
    elseif($d1 < $d2) return -1 ;
    else return 1 ;
}

usort($dates, 'myCompDates');

print_r($dates);
```

Output :

> Array
>
> (
>
> [0] => June 8-12
>
> [1] => June 15-19
>
> [2] => June 22-26
>
> [3] => June 29 - July 2
>
> [4] => July 6-10
>
> [5] => July 8
>
> [6] => July 10-24
>
> [7] => July 13-17
>
> [8] => July 20-24
>
> [9] => July 27-31
>
> [10] => August 3-7
>
> [11] => August 10-14
>
> )

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution really helped me.